# Previewing the sql code generated by NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Using NHibernate 2.0:

I have an object with some changes on it and I am about to session.Update() it. Is there some way I can preview the SQL that will be executed without actually executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap a transaction around the session and perform the update without committing.

Comment: Good idea, not best performance, but for tests good enough, if NHibernate does not lock too many rows.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that. I guess this is the only sure way of seeing the generated SQL in all it's glory! :-) Thanks.

Comment: Note to self: .Flush() before tx.Rollback()

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do that? You can show it by the show-sql setting, but it will be executed also. You could use NHibernate againt an in-memory database like SQLite if you want to test the mapping ;)

Best Regards
Oliver Hanappi

Comment: I know, but I'm stuck with this live legacy database, I'm paranoid, and I'm curious. :-)

Comment: @Per Erik, you are walking on thin ice my friend. I would seriously suggest working off a backup/snapshot, then would be free to test and break things.